# How to check if a number is prime in a more efficient manner?

Tags: c++, primes

So I have the following problem. They give me an array w/ n numbers and I have to print if it contains any prime numbers using "Divide et Impera". I solved the problem but it gets only 70/100 because it isn't efficient(they say).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int x){
   if(x == 2) return false;
   for(int i = 2; i <= x/2; ++i)
      if(x%i==0) return false;
   return true;

}

int existaP(int a[], int li, int ls){
    if(li==ls)
       if(isPrime(a[li]) == true) return 1;
       else return 0;
    else  return existaP(a, li, (li+ls)/2)+existaP(a, (li+ls)/2+1, ls);      
}

int main(){
   int n, a[10001];
   cin >> n;
   for(int i = 1; i<=n; ++i) cin >> a[i];
   if(existaP(a,1,n) >= 1) cout << "Y";
   else cout << "N";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(x == 2) return false;` Why is this returning false? 2 is a prime number.

Comment: What's the added value of recursion in `existaP()`? Is the input array sorted?

Comment: Read [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) wikipage. And your question is *not* C++ specific, and is off-topic (since asking for resources ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lowest hanging fruit here is your stopping conditional

```
i <= x/2
```

which can be replaced with

```
i * i <= x
```

having taken care to ensure you don't overflow an `int`.This is because you only need to go up to the square root of `x`, rather than half way. Perhaps `i <= x / i` is better still as that avoids the overflow; albeit at the expense of a division which can be relatively costly on some platforms.

Your algorithm is also defective for `x == 2` as you have the incorrect return value. It would be better if you dropped that extra test, as the ensuing loop covers it.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you only need to go up to the square root of `x`, rather than half way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an efficinent way to check prime number.

```
 bool isPrime(int num) {
        if(num <= 1) return false;
        if (num <= 3)  return true; 
        
        int range = sqrt(num);
        // This is checked so that we can skip 
        // middle five numbers in below loop 
        if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) 
            return false; 
        

        for (int i = 5; i <= range; i += 6) 
            if (num % i == 0 || num % (i + 2) == 0) 
                return false; 
        
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is great! Shaved off 5 seconds for a range of 1,000 in the in the 1 quadrillion space compared to the primality test I was using prior.

Comment: 399949993 output this number as prime... while it is not.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isprime(int x)
{
    if(x <= 1) return false;
    if(x == 2 || x == 3) return true;
    if(x % 2 == 0 || x % 3 == 0) return false;
    if((x - 1) % 6 != 0 && (x + 1) % 6 != 0) return false;
    for(int i = 5; i * i <= x; i += 6)
    {
        if(x % i == 0 || x % (i + 2) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If prime numbers need to be printed for a particular range or to determine whether a number is prime or not, [the sieve of the eratosthenes algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/) is probably preferable as it is very efficient in terms of time complexity `O( n * log2( log2(n) ) )`, but the space complexity of this algorithm can cause an issue if the numbers are exceeding certain memory limit.

We can optimize [this simpler algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-to-check-whether-a-number-is-prime-or-not/) which has a time complexity of `O(n1/2)` [by introducing few additional checks based on this thoerem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41623/is-that-true-that-all-the-prime-numbers-are-of-the-form-6m-pm-1) as shown in the above `isprime code block`.

Despite the fact that Sieve of Erathosthenes algorithm is efficient in terms of time complexity under space restrictions, the above provided `isprime code block` can be utilized, and there are numerous variations of the Sieve of Erathosthenes algorithm that perform considerably better, as explained in [this link](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/sieve-of-eratosthenes.html#asymptotic-analysis).

Many more algorithms exist, but in terms of solving coding challenges, this one is simpler and more convenient. You can learn more about them by clicking on the following links:

1. https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-algorithm-to-check-if-a-number-is-prime
2. [https://www.baeldung.com/cs/prime-number-algorithms#:~:text=Most%20algorithms%20for%20finding%20prime,test%20or%20Miller%2DRabin%20method](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/prime-number-algorithms#:%7E:text=Most%20algorithms%20for%20finding%20prime,test%20or%20Miller%2DRabin%20method).

Comment: Could you explain your codes a bit about how it is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

A stander way(maybe..?) is just check from i = 0 to  the sqrt(number)

```
bool isPrime(int num){
    if(num == 1) return false;
    for(int i = 2;i<=sqrt(num);i++){
          if(num % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code will give a wrong answer if n is 1.**

Your time complexity can be decreased to **sqrt(n)** , where **n is the number**.

Here is the code

```
bool isPrime(long int n)
{
  if (n == 1)
  {
    return false;
  }
  int i = 2;
  while (i*i <= n)
  {
      if (n % i == 0)
      {
          return false;
      }
      i += 1;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The "long int" will help to avoid overflow.

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are not too big you could also try to solve this using the sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
constexpr int LIMIT = 100001;
// not_prime because global variables are initialized with 0
bool not_prime[LIMIT];

void sieve() {
    int i, j;
    not_prime[2] = false;

    for(int i = 2; i < LIMIT; ++i) 
        if(!not_prime[i])
            for(int j = i + i; j < LIMIT; j += i) 
                not_prime[j] = true;
}

int existaP(int a[], int li, int ls){
    if(li==ls)
       if(!not_prime[a[li]] == true) 
           return 1;
       else  
           return 0;
    else   
           return existaP(a, li, (li + ls) / 2) + existaP(a, (li + ls) / 2 + 1, ls);      
}

int main(){
   int n, a[10001];
   cin >> n;
   for(int i = 1; i<=n; ++i) cin >> a[i];

   sieve();

   if(existaP(a,1,n) >= 1) cout << "Y";
   else cout << "N";
   return 0;
}
```

Basically when you encounter a prime all the numbers that are a multiple of it won't be primes.

P.S.: Acum am vazut ca esti roman :)
Poti sa te uiti aici pentru a optimiza si mai mult algoritmul: https://infoarena.ro/ciurul-lui-eratostene

Answer (score 0):

Another inefficiency not yet mentioned is `existaP(a, li, (li+ls)/2) + existaP(a, (li+ls)/2+1, ls);`

In particular, the problem here is the `+`. If you know `existaP(a, li, (li+ls)/2)` > 0, then `existaP(a, (li+ls)/2+1, ls)` no longer matters. In other words, you're currently counting the **exact** number of unique factors, but as soon as you know a number has **at least** two factors you know it's not prime.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one efficient way to check a given number is prime.**

```
 bool isprime(int n) {
    if(n<=1)
        return false;

    if(n<=3)
        return true;

    if(n%2==0||n%3==0)
        return false;

    for(int i=5;i*i<=n;i=i+6) {
        if(n%i==0||n%(i+2)==0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a much faster algorithm in my opinion. It works on the Euclidean algorithm to calculate H.C.F. Basically, I check if the HCF of the number AND the consecutively second number is 1; and if the number itself is divisible by either 2 or 3. Don't ask how I mathematically reached the solution, it just struck me :D. The time complexity of this solution is O(log (max(a,b))), which is notably smaller than the time complexity of the program which runs a loop counter 2 to sqrt(n) is O(sqrt(n)).

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int hcf(int, int);
    
    int hcf(int a, int b)
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            return a;
        }
    
        return hcf(b, a % b);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int a;
    
        cout << "\nEnter a natural number: ";
        cin >> a;
    
        if(a<=0)
        {
            cout << "\nFor conventional reasons we keep the discussion of primes to natural numbers in this program:) (Read: Ring of Integers / Euclid's Lemma)";
            return 0;
        }
    
        if (a == 1)
        {
            cout << "\nThe number is neither composite nor prime :D";
            return 0;
        }
    
        if (a == 2)
        {
            cout << "\nThe number is the only even Prime :D";
            return 0;
        }
    
        if (hcf(a, a + 2) == 1)
        {
            if (a % 2 != 0 && a % 3 != 0)
            {
                cout << "\nThe number is a Prime :D";
                return 0;
            }
        }
    
        cout << "\nThe number is not a Prime D:";
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm a student.

Comment: My implementation of this in javascript results in maximum call stack size exceeded at `return a`

Comment: when i enter 25, it say it is a prime :D lol